Problem when training my model with fit_generator or model.fit does not show val_loss and val_acc
I'm training my model and during the training step the validation isn't happening. I've checked the paths and the data and they're all ok. I don't know what possible reason, because at first it worked. I've tried several versions of tensorflow and keras and I can't find the problem. Below I will put the training code and the data generator:
def main():
 goTrain()

# input image dimensions

def goTrain():
 params = {'batch_size':32,
         'dim':(128,128,128),
         'n_channels':1,
         'shuffle': True}

seismPathT = "./data/train/seis/"
faultPathT = "./data/train/fault/"

train_ID = range(200)
valid_ID = range(20)
train_generator = DataGenerator(dpath=seismPathT,fpath=faultPathT, data_IDs=train_ID,**params)
valid_generator = DataGenerator(dpath=seismPathV,fpath=faultPathV, data_IDs=valid_ID,**params)
model = unet(input_size=(None, None, None,1))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

# checkpoint

filepath="check1/fseg-{epoch:02d}.keras"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy',verbose=1, mode='max')
logging = TrainValTensorBoard()
callbacks_list = [checkpoint,logging]
print("data prepared, ready to train!")

# Fit the model

print(history.history.keys())
model.save('check1/fseg.keras')
showHistory(history)

def showHistory(history):

# list all data in history

print(history.history.keys())
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

# summarize history for accuracy

plt.plot(history.history\['accuracy'\])
plt.plot(history.history\['val_accuracy'\])
plt.title('Model accuracy',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Accuracy',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Epoch',fontsize=20)
plt.legend(\['train', 'test'\], loc='center right',fontsize=20)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=18)
plt.show()

# summarize history for loss

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(history.history\['loss'\])
plt.plot(history.history\['val_loss'\])
plt.title('Model loss',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Loss',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Epoch',fontsize=20)
plt.legend(\['train', 'test'\], loc='center right',fontsize=20)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=18)
plt.show()

class TrainValTensorBoard(TensorBoard):
def _init_(self, log_dir='./log', \*\*kwargs):
training_log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'training')
super(TrainValTensorBoard, self)._init_(training_log_dir, \*\*kwargs)
self.val_log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'validation')

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.val_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(self.val_log_dir)
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).set_model(model)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        val_logs = {k.replace('val_', ''): v for k, v in logs.items() if 'val_' in k}
        with self.val_writer.as_default():
            for name, value in val_logs.items():
                tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=epoch)
        self.val_writer.flush()
        logs = {k: v for k, v in logs.items() if not 'val_' in k}
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).on_train_end(logs)
        self.val_writer.close()

if _name_ == '_main_':
main()

You can see during training that it's not performing validation:
Total params: 1459585 (5.57 MB)
Trainable params: 1459585 (5.57 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
data prepared, ready to train!

1/1 \[==============================\] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6623 - accuracy: 0.9086
Epoch 1: saving model to check1\\fseg-01.keras

And at the end, it returns the error stating that it does not have the validation metrics stored:
dict_keys(\['loss', 'accuracy'\])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Users\\nilo\\Music\\faultSeg-master\\train.py", line 175, in \<module\>
main()
File "c:\\Users\\nilo\\Music\\faultSeg-master\\train.py", line 18, in main
goTrain()
File "c:\\Users\\nilo\\Music\\faultSeg-master\\train.py", line 59, in goTrain
showHistory(history)
File "c:\\Users\\nilo\\Music\\faultSeg-master\\train.py", line 68, in showHistory
plt.plot(history.history\['val_accuracy'\])
\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'val_accuracy'


1- try to put the indentations correctly. 2- use \``pythonto colorize the codes. 3- I couldn't see anymodel.train` in that function you need to pass the validation data. for more info check here

Sorry, I erased the line, here is the model.fit:
history=model.fit(train_generator,validation_data=valid_generator,callbacks=callbacks_list, epochs=100, verbose=1)

Are you using the old version of TensorFlow? In the past versions passing generators as the validation data has this effect. so first try to update your tensorflow, if it doesn't help try to convert valid_generator into a regular tensor.
